# "Cannot find certificates that match the key." When trying to sign Visual Studio project using makecert.exe and pvk2pfx.bat

Tags: .net, certificate, sign

Since I installed a new computer, my only signed project is not compiling due to certificate failure. I tried pointing the project to the certificate file but it appears to be linked to the previous user/computer.
I'm not much experimented with certifictes/signing as I don't use them often.

I don't remember the procedure I used previously to sign the project, yet I'm hoping to find something that would not create a dependancy between the project and computer.

I'm trying to follow this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/appxpkg/how-to-create-a-package-signing-certificate

And I ran ( [ ] and X indicate parts of the code that have been anonymised for posting here)

```
makecert -r -pe -ss PrivateCertStore -n "CN=[My Name]" X.cer
```

Which creates file "X.cer"

```
makecert /n "[My Name]" /r /h 0 /eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" /sv X.pvk X.cer
```

Which creates file "X.pvk"

```
pvk2pfx /pvk X.pvk /pi "[the key passowrd]" /spc X.cer /pfx X.pfx
```

Which I expect to create file "X.pfx"

But instead I get

> ERROR: Cannot find certificates that match the key. (Error Code = 0x80070490).

Comment: The first part of that article is very important.

Comment: Thank you. I must say I'm a bit confused because all I'm trying to do is to create is a .cer file that I can direct VS to. In project "Properties" > "Signing" > "Sign the ClickOnce manifests", then I package an installation .exe file using an Installer creator called "Inno setup" ... so that the .exe file install smoothly on user computers ... but all articles I find talk aboutcreating other packages and uploading things in Windows Store, which is not what I'm wanting to do.

Comment: Back to the very basics, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps Learn what kind of certificate you need and use PowerShell to generate it.

Comment: Thank you. I've created a very basic certificate ( New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type CodeSigningCert -Subject "CN=[Name]" ) not sure if I'm missing something ... Output was a "thumbprint" ... I expected a file, not sure where this is stored nor the next steps

Comment: I found how to export it from the Mananement Console to a *.pfx file. Not sure about some of the export options, will still need to test if works with my software.